# Perform action based on hash tag in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page, I have:

```
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<div></div>
<a href="#2">Link 2</a>
<div></div>
<a href="#3">Link 3</a>
<div></div>
```

Say a user goes to this page:

> http://www.mysite.com/vendors#3

Then I'd like to add a css class to the link with `href="#3"`. How can I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it. You check the window hash value.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a[href="' +window.location.hash + '"]').addClass('activeLink');
});
```

You might need to add the # in there manually. Forget if it is included in hash value.

Comment: in my experience, the hash is present when you read that property, but isn't necessary when you set it.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onhashchange = (function() {
    var newHash = window.location.hash;
    $('a[href="' + newHash + '"]').addClass("yourClass");
    return arguments.callee;
})();
```

This will run when the document has been accessed and when you click on a link referencing a hash.

Comment: two questions: why did you use an IIFE? why do return arguments.callee?